# How to set state with file object (react)

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I want to setState with file Object using 'redux'.
But, It doesn't set state with input value.

Input tag (below)

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={onChange}
      multiple
    />
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript method executing reducer with action.payload (below)

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { ModalActions } = this.props;
    ModalActions.imageChange({
      image: e.target.files
    })
  }
```

Reducer setting state

```
  [IMAGE_CHANGE]: (state, action) => {
    console.log(action.payload.image)
    return state.set('images', List(action.payload.image))
  }
```

I got result due to use console.log in reducer (below)

[console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnIc0.png)

And It doesn't set state with payload

[state result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKBts.png)

Comment: image: e.target.files[0] and lose the List, use only action.payload.image

Comment: @Roy.B I did it. But still doesn't work. I use <input multiple/>, and It' is right that I use 'e.target.files'

Comment: ok, so change state.set to state.setIn

Comment: @Roy.B You mean that I should change state.setIn(['images', '...'], List(action.payload.image)) ?? It doesn't work too.. and initialState is "images: List([ ])"

Comment: see my answer below